# Make player double jump Sprite Kit Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have implemented a single jump for my player. But I want the player to be able to double jump if the user taps twice.

How do I make this function below check to see if the jump is still in duration, so that they can tap and jump again if they want?

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    var isJumping = false
    var isDoubleJumping = false

    if mario.action(forKey: "jump") == nil && isJumping {

        let marioTextureJump = SKTexture(imageNamed: "mariojump.png")

        let animation = SKAction.animate(with: [marioTextureJump], timePerFrame: 0.6)

        mario.run(animation)

        mario.run(jumpAction, withKey: "jump")

        if isJumping {

            isDoubleJumping = true
            isJumping = false
        }

        else {

            isJumping = true
            isDoubleJumping = false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this might be to just add 2 flags to your scene

```
isPlayerJumping = false
isPlayerDoubleJumping = false
```

and then check for and set those variables in your touches func

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent {

    //if the player is already double jumping don't let them jump again until finished
    guard !isDoubleJumping else { return }

    let animation = SKAction.animate(with: [playerTextureJump], timePerFrame: 0.6)

    player.run(animation)

    if isJumping {
        isDoubleJumping = true
        isJumping = false

        player.run(jumpAction, withKey: "jump") {
            self.isDoubleJumping = false
        }
    }
    else {
        isJumping = true

        player.run(jumpAction, withKey: "jump") {
            self.isJumping = false
        }
    }
}
```

> EDIT

If you don't want to use guard you can just put an `if statement` in place

```
if isPlayerDoubleJumping {
    return
}
```

At the end of your jumpAction you have to run a block of code to reset the variables

```
SKAction.run {
    isJumping = false
    isDoubleJumping = false
}
```

you could even change the variables inline in your touches began like so...

```
player.run(jumpAction, withKey: "jump") {
    self.isPlayerJumping = false
    self.isPlayerDoubleJumping = false
}
```

Comment: I don't have a player class so this won't work. Can you edit your answer to account for this please? Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry but I still can't get it right. I've never used guard before so I don't know how that works. Ive edited my code to show you where I'm at.

Comment: guard is just a fancy "if statement" I've adjusted my answer to show you the difference

Comment: Perfect. Works great now! Thanks!

Comment: great! best of luck in your game!

Comment: There is a problem with this though, the player can spam taps before he leaves the ground so they can essentially jump as high as they want.

Comment: make sure that you have the variables isJumping & isDoubleJumping declared in the class, not in the touchesBegan func. otherwise they'll always be getting replaced

Comment: Then they can only jump once and cannot jump or double jump after that.

Comment: you'll have to update your code so that I can see what's happening. just add it to the bottom. don't take away your original code

Comment: Too long to post here. How about I show you in chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151543/discussion-between-jack-richards-and-ron-myschuk).